# DICOM to Point Cloud in VTK

Tags: image-processing, vtk, data-conversion, medical-imaging

Is there any method for converting DICOM (ct scan) images to Point Clouds using VTK?

VTK allows reading DICOM and DICOM series and volume rendering but is it possible to generate a Point Cloud from a series of DICOM images?

If it isn't possible in VTK, is there some other library that I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dicom to point cloud demonstration.  Dicom files are pretty variable depending on how the imaging is collected, but this is what we have been using for CT scans for some time.  This is the "manual version" ie where you will need to interact with the terminal to navigate the dicom directory.  It is possible to automate this but is highly dependent on your application.

I have pcl 8.0 and vtkdicom installed.  (i was able to do a limited implementation of this without vtkdicom, but its features make the application far more robust at handling diverse dicom directory structures).

You will need to point the function in the main towards the appropriate directory on your computer (should be the file containing the DICOMDIR file).  Once you have loaded the dicom, the visualizer has keyboard inputs m and n to control intensity target to be visualized.  (you can easily change the code to filter for any of the parameters: x,y,z,intensity) and can change the width or stepsize as needed.

```
#include <pcl/common/common_headers.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
#include <pcl/filters/passthrough.h>

#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkDICOMImageReader.h>
#include "vtkImageData.h"
#include "vtkDICOMDirectory.h"
#include "vtkDICOMItem.h"
#include "vtkStringArray.h"
#include "vtkIntArray.h"
#include "vtkDICOMReader.h"


bool loadDICOM(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr outCloud, std::string fullPathToDicomDir)
{
    // load DICOM dir file
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMDirectory> ddir =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMDirectory>::New();
    ddir->SetDirectoryName(fullPathToDicomDir.c_str());
    ddir->Update();

    //select patient
    int n = ddir->GetNumberOfPatients();
    int patientSelection = 0;
    if (n > 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Select Patient number, total count: " << n << std::endl;
        std::string userInput;
        std::getline(std::cin, userInput);
        patientSelection = std::stoi(userInput);
    }
    const vtkDICOMItem& patientItem = ddir->GetPatientRecord(patientSelection);
    std::cout << "Patient " << patientSelection << ": " << patientItem.Get(DC::PatientID).AsString() << "\n";

    //select study
    vtkIntArray* studies = ddir->GetStudiesForPatient(patientSelection);
    vtkIdType m = studies->GetMaxId() + 1;
    int studySelection = 0;
    if (m > 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Select study, total count: " << m << std::endl;
        std::string userInput;
        std::getline(std::cin, userInput);
        studySelection = std::stoi(userInput);
    }

    int j = studies->GetValue(studySelection);
    const vtkDICOMItem& studyItem = ddir->GetStudyRecord(j);
    const vtkDICOMItem& studyPItem = ddir->GetPatientRecordForStudy(j);
    cout << " Study " << j << ": \""
        << studyItem.Get(DC::StudyDescription).AsString() << "\" \""
        << studyPItem.Get(DC::PatientName).AsString() << "\" "
        << studyItem.Get(DC::StudyDate).AsString() << "\n";
    int k0 = ddir->GetFirstSeriesForStudy(j);
    int k1 = ddir->GetLastSeriesForStudy(j);

    int seriesSelection;
    std::cout << "Select series, range: " << k0 << " to " << k1 << std::endl;
    for (int i = k0; i <= k1; i++)
    {
        const vtkDICOMItem& seriesItem = ddir->GetSeriesRecord(i);
        vtkStringArray* a = ddir->GetFileNamesForSeries(i);

        cout << "  Series " << i << ": \""
            << seriesItem.Get(DC::SeriesDescription).AsString() << "\" "
            << seriesItem.Get(DC::SeriesNumber).AsString() << " "
            << seriesItem.Get(DC::Modality).AsString() << ", Images: "
            << a->GetNumberOfTuples() << "\n";
    }

    std::string userInput;
    std::getline(std::cin, userInput);
    seriesSelection = std::stoi(userInput);

    const vtkDICOMItem& seriesItem = ddir->GetSeriesRecord(seriesSelection);
    cout << "  Series " << seriesSelection << ": \""
        << seriesItem.Get(DC::SeriesDescription).AsString() << "\" "
        << seriesItem.Get(DC::SeriesNumber).AsString() << " "
        << seriesItem.Get(DC::Modality).AsString() << "\n";

    vtkStringArray* a = ddir->GetFileNamesForSeries(seriesSelection);
    vtkDICOMReader* reader = vtkDICOMReader::New();
    reader->SetFileNames(a);
    reader->Update();



    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> sliceData = reader->GetOutput();

    int numberOfDims = sliceData->GetDataDimension();
    int* dims = sliceData->GetDimensions();
    std::cout << "Cloud dimensions: ";
    int totalPoints = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDims; i++)
    {
        std::cout << dims[i] << " , ";
        totalPoints = totalPoints * dims[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Number of dicom points: " << totalPoints << std::endl;


    //read data into grayCloud

    double* dataRange = sliceData->GetScalarRange();
    double* spacingData = reader->GetDataSpacing();
    std::cout << "Data intensity bounds... min: " << dataRange[0] << ", max: " << dataRange[1] << std::endl;
    if (numberOfDims != 3)
    {
        std::cout << "Incorrect number of dimensions in dicom file, generation failed..." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Eigen::RowVector3f spacing = Eigen::RowVector3f(spacingData[0], spacingData[1], spacingData[2]);
        Eigen::RowVector3i dimensions = Eigen::RowVector3i(dims[0], dims[1], dims[2]);

        outCloud->points.clear();

        std::cout << "x spacing: " << spacing(0) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "y spacing: " << spacing(1) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "z spacing: " << spacing(2) << std::endl;

        for (int z = 0; z < dims[2]; z++)
        {
            if (z % 50 == 0)
            {
                double percentageComplete = (double)z / (double)dims[2];
                std::cout << "Dicom Read Progress: " << (int)(100.0 * percentageComplete) << "%" << std::endl;
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < dims[1]; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < dims[0]; x++)
                {
                    double tempIntensity = sliceData->GetScalarComponentAsDouble(x, y, z, 0);

                    int tempX = x;

                    pcl::PointXYZI tempPt = pcl::PointXYZI();
                    

                    if (!isinf(tempIntensity) && !isnan(tempIntensity))
                    {
                        //map value into positive realm
                        //tempIntensity = ((tempIntensity - dataRange[0]) / (dataRange[1] - dataRange[0]));
                        if (tempIntensity > SHRT_MAX) { tempIntensity = SHRT_MAX; }
                        else if (tempIntensity < SHRT_MIN) { tempIntensity = SHRT_MIN; }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tempIntensity = 0;
                    }

                    tempPt.x = tempX;
                    tempPt.y = y;
                    tempPt.z = z;
                    tempPt.intensity = tempIntensity;
                    outCloud->points.push_back(tempPt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Load Dicom Cloud Complete!" << std::endl;
    return true;
}


int indexSlice = 0;
void keyboardEventOccurred(const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent& event, void* viewer)
{
    if (event.getKeySym() == "n" && event.keyDown())
    {
        indexSlice -= 1;
    }
    else if (event.getKeySym() == "m" && event.keyDown())
    {
        indexSlice += 1;
    }
}

void displayCloud(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloud, std::string field, int step, int width, std::string window_name = "default")
{
    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer(window_name));

    viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 2, "id");

    viewer->registerKeyboardCallback(keyboardEventOccurred, (void*)viewer.get());

    
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr tempCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);

    pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZI> pass;
    pass.setInputCloud(cloud);
    pass.setFilterFieldName(field); //could gate this on intensity if u preferred

    int lastIndex = indexSlice-1; //proc first cycle
    while (!viewer->wasStopped()) {
        
        if (indexSlice != lastIndex)
        {
            int low = step * indexSlice - width / 2;
            int high = step * indexSlice + width / 2;
            pass.setFilterLimits(low, high);
            pass.filter(*tempCloud);
            lastIndex = indexSlice;
            std::cout << field<< " range: " <<low<<" , "<<high<< std::endl;

            viewer->removeAllPointClouds();
            pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerGenericField<pcl::PointXYZI> point_cloud_color_handler(tempCloud, "intensity");
            viewer->addPointCloud< pcl::PointXYZI >(tempCloud, point_cloud_color_handler, "id");
        }
        
        viewer->spinOnce(50);
    }
    viewer->close();
}

// --------------
// -----Main-----
// --------------
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
    loadDICOM(cloud, "C:/Local Software/voyDICOM/resources/DICOM_Samples/2021APR14 MiniAchors_V0");
    displayCloud(cloud,"intensity",100,50);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in most cases dicom files are relatively massive in terms of raw dimensions and so I very rarely (never?) have loaded a whole dicom file into a point cloud (until for this code).  Generally what I do is handle it in a dense format (short array) and then create clouds based on selections from that data.  This way you can do certain imaging operations that benefit from a locked data grid (opening, closing, etc) prior to going to the sparse data set (point cloud) where everything becomes profoundly more expensive.

Pretty picture of it working with one of my debug dicom sets:
[image]

Comment: Could you please share your full code. I am also looking for the code of same problem.

Comment: @Js541 Doubt you still have this issue, but lmk if this gives you any grief.

Answer (score -2):

I think I might have found a way, after all. Haven't tried it yet but in theory it should work.

Firstly, the DICOM image needs to be converted into .vtk format using VTK once the DICOM images have been converted into .vtk they can then be converted into .pcd (Point cloud format) using PCL (point cloud library).